# Reset JavaScript Counter after Deleting a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that adds input fields with a counter. now, when i remove one of the fields it gets deleted but the counter continues! is there a way in JS or JQuery to reset the counter and auto increment the counter?

JS code:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value'+i+'" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();

                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/13816/)

Clarifying:
my fields are like:

```
no. 1
no. 2
no. 3
```

what i want is: After deleting #2:

```
no. 1
no. 3
**To**:
no. 1
no. 2
```

Thank you

Comment: use .length, .index,  .on and preventDefault - each added item knows its own .index

Comment: @mplungjan please check the clarification example.

Comment: My free airport internet is too slow to give an example. Sorry

Comment: @mplungjan Clarifying: my fields are like:

`no. 1
no. 2
no. 3
what i want is: After deleting #2:

no. 1
no. 3
**To**:
no. 1
no. 2`

Comment: @Disputed just a side note: with this code you are going to have many elements with the same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Js

```
function resetIndexes(){
    var j = 1;   
    $('.p_scnt').each(function(){
        if( j > 1){
            $(this).attr('name', 'p_scnt_' + j);
            $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Input Value'+j);
        }   
        j++;    
    });
}


$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
        i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;   
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" class="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value'+i+'" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    resetIndexes();
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5gxjmss/8/)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use .on() instead of .live() as it's mostly suggested

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following?

```
       $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
              i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Yes, if you remove in the middle it'll just go -- to the last item and will be duplicated.

Comment: @Alex Pavlov is right, in addition you would be forced to update the placeholders as well.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion, NOT the answer.

Well you must need to change 'live' for 'on'

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
```

with on

```
$('document.body').on('click', '#addScnt', function() {
```

[jQuery live deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: I tried to change into .on() but it did not work with me.