# How can one reset a JavaScript variable count upon deleting a field?

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, counter

I read through the [Reset JavaScript Counter after Deleting a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639850/reset-javascript-counter-after-deleting-a-field) however it did not seem to fit fully what I am asking.

As my question states, is it possible to reset a counter variable when multiple fields share that variable as part of their ID and use for a header indicating which new row of fields has been added?

See my JSFiddle to see what I am talking about.  Add up to about 6 or 7 people and then hit either one of the deletes.

https://jsfiddle.net/Born2Discover/e4up2pfs/1/

```html
<script>
  var mycount = 1;
  var mylimit = 10;

  // My Add Function

  function addSomeone(addPerson) {



    if (mycount == mylimit) {
      alert("You have reached the max number of people " + mycount + " inputs");
    } else {
      var newPersonDiv = document.createElement('div');
      newPersonDiv.id = ("Person" + (mycount + 1) + "Div");
      newPersonDiv.innerHTML = "<br/><span>Person " + (mycount + 1) + "</span><br/><label>First</label><input type='text' name='FirstName" + (mycount + 1) + "'><label>Middle</label><input type='text' name='MiddleName" + (mycount + 1) + "'><label>Last</label><input type='text' name='LaneName" + (mycount + 1) + "'><span onClick='deleteDIV()'> Delete</button></span>";
      document.getElementById(addPerson).appendChild(newPersonDiv);
      mycount++;
    }

  }

  // My Delete Function

  function deleteDIV() {
    //Desired function to delete new fields and reset counter
    Person4Div.remove(); // < this part posted for reference
    //This would obviously delete Div4 but would not reset the counter and numbers
    //Click to add 6 people for example and then hit delete on either one to see what I mean
  }

</script>
<input type="button" value="Add Person" onclick="addSomeone('new');">

<div id="addPerson">
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="First Name">
    <label>Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Middle Name">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Last Name">
    <div id="new"></div>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I think I know understand what you want

First of all your button is not a button, since it starts with `<span>`.
Make that

```
<button onClick='deleteDIV(event)'>Delete</button>
```

Note the `event` inside the brackets. That is important. This allows you to access the actual event and with `event.target` you get the actual target element, the button in this case.

Add a `data-number` attribute to your div, this makes it a lot easier to retrieve the number

```
newPersonDiv.setAttribute('data-number', mycount+1);
```

Change your *deleteDIV* function like this:

```
function deleteDIV() {
    // prevents the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    // the number of the element that is deleted
    var number = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-number');

    // the next div after the one to be deleted
    var nextPersonInput = event.target.parentNode.nextSibling;

    // as long as there is a next div
    while(nextPersonInput != null){

        // decrease the data-number by 1
        nextPersonInput.setAttribute('data-number', nextPersonInput.getAttribute('data-number') - 1);

        // move one div further
        nextPersonInput = nextPersonInput.nextSibling;
    }

    // delete the div itself     
    document.getElementById('new').removeChild(event.target.parentNode);

    // decrease the counter
    // since you only delete 1 element at once just decreasing by 1 is sufficient
    mycount--; 

}
```

Since `event.target` is the `button`, its *parentNode* refers to the `div`, which is a child of the **new** `div`.

This way you don't even have to insert the Id to the divs anymore.

What is left is to actually alter the displayed information and the attributes such as `name` and `middlename`. So far the displayed numbers are not yet altered. But I think you should manage to do that. If not, just ask me.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe here is a better way to explain where I hope to go with this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639850/reset-javascript-counter-after-deleting-a-field

Using this working demo, how can I add 3 fields to the dynamic content, and keep the numbers flowing correct.  With one field, they work just as I desire, but when you add more fields the numbers get all messed up.