# How to exchange counter after delete field using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in javascript. i have a JS function that add and remove input fields. its working fine with my JS function. But I want when delete a field its Id looks like:
**I have**
no. 1
no. 2
no. 3
**After Delete 2**:
no. 1
no. 2

already i got this answer:
[Reset JavaScript Counter after Deleting a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639850/reset-javascript-counter-after-deleting-a-field)

But i want it with plain javascript. Can anyone help?

```
<script>
    var count = 1;
    function add_new(){
        count++;
        var div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.id = count;
        var delLink = '<button type="button" onclick="deleteLink('+count+')" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>';
        div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('add_link1').innerHTML+delLink;
        document.getElementById('add_link').appendChild(div1);
        document.getElementById("input_link1").id = count;
        document.getElementById("input_link2").id = count;
        document.getElementById("input_link3").id = count;

    }

    function deleteLink(eleId){
        var ele = document.getElementById(eleId);
        var par = document.getElementById('add_link');
        par.removeChild(ele);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting an element call the following function to reset Id of existing elements and also reduce the count.

```js
function reset_counter(deletedCount) {
  for (var impactedElementId = deletedCount + 1; impactedElementId < count; impactedElementId++) {
    var currentElement = document.getElementById(impactedElementId);
    currentElement.id = impactedElementId - 1;
    var button = currentElement.firstChild;
    button.innerHTML = 'Delete ' + currentElement.id;
    button.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteLink(' + currentElement.id + ')');
  }
  count--;
}
```

The full code is available here: [AddDeleteElements Sample Code](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/web/stack/57055651-AddDeleteElement.html)